# Bootstrap Angular 2 with Angular 1

Tags: angularjs, upgrade, ng-upgrade

I have `app.js` in angular `1.4`. app.js contains the following:

```
var app = angular.module('testingBoot',[...], function(){});
```

I am making another file : `test.ts`. This contains the following :

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {UpgradeAdapter} from 'angular2/upgrade';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';

const upgradeAdapter = new UpgradeAdapter();
upgradeAdapter.bootstrap(document.body, ['testingBoot']);
```

`Index.html` :

```
<script src="/flat-ui/libs/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/flat-ui/libs/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="/flat-ui/libs/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="/flat-ui/libs/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="/flat-ui/libs/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="/flat-ui/libs/angular2.dev.js"></script>
<script>
 System.config({
       baseURL : '/',
       defaultJSExtension: true,
       map: {
           mainTest : './flat-ui/js/typeScript',
           angular2 : '/flat-ui/libs/angular2'
       },
        packages: {
          mainTest: {
              format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
          },
          angular2 : {
              baseURL : '/flat-ui/libs/angular2',
              defaultExtension: 'js'
          }
        }
      });
 System.import('mainTest/test')
      .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/flat/js/app.js"></script>
```

Till this all works fine and the angular 1 app bootstraps well.

Now the issue is that I need to include a component created in Angular 2 into Angular 1 as a directive.

The docs say that all I need to write is :

```
angular.module('testingBoot').directive('testingOnActivity', upgradeAdapter.downgradeNg2Component(AppComponent));
```

But where and in which file do I include this? If I include this in test.ts then I get the error that `angular` is not  defined and I cannot include this in app.js as then `upgradeAdapter` is not present and app.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include it between:

```
const upgradeAdapter = new UpgradeAdapter();
upgradeAdapter.bootstrap(document.body, ['testingBoot']);
```

my boot.ts:

```
import {UpgradeAdapter} from 'angular2/upgrade';
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser'
import {AppComponent} from './app.component'

declare var angular:any;

export const upgradeAdapter = new UpgradeAdapter();
myApp.directive('testDirective', upgradeAdapter.downgradeNg2Component(AppComponent));

upgradeAdapter.bootstrap(document.body, ['myApp']);
```